Can somebody explain how this shared_ptr example works?
I try to understand how this example of chat_server from boost::asio documentation works.
I have such handler for async_accept:
void chat_server::do_accept()
  {
    acceptor_.async_accept(
        [this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            std::make_shared<chat_session>(std::move(socket), room_)->start(); //????
          }
          std::cout << "Server: wait for new connection\n";
          do_accept();
        });
  }

So, as I understand from this function: acceptor creates socket and returns it to the lambda function. Because I don't have any mention of variable socket.
My question is about this line:
std::make_shared<chat_session>(std::move(socket), room_)->start();

As I understand, it creates an anonymous shared pointer to the class chat_session, moves the received socket to it and adds a reference to room_, and mean while run function start()?

How can I rewrite this code in more lines? For example:

chat_session A(std::move(socket), room_); // create class
std::make_shared<chat_session>(A);
A->start()


As I understand from basic_socket_acceptor::async_accept, I should create socket for myself and add it to acceptor. But in this function, it creates for itself by acceptor?

I try to understand how this function works.

The magic in this example is done using std::enable_shared_from_this, which enables an object to create shared pointers to itself, the following code creates a temporary shared_ptr and calls start on it.
std::make_shared<chat_session>(std::move(socket), room_)->start();

Normally such code would delete the object at the end of the line, but because of shared_from_this you are able to create other shared_pointers inside start, thus extending the object's lifetime.
void start()
{
  // creates another shared_ptr to `this` and stores it inside room_
  room_.join(shared_from_this());  
  do_read_header(); // creates another shared_ptr internally
}

In order to make use of std::enable_shared_from_this the object needs to be allocated on the heap (or at least not have automatic storage), hence the following code will also work.
std::shared_ptr<chat_session> ptr{new chat_session(std::move(socket), room_)};
ptr->start();

The use of make_shared here optimizes the memory allocation of the control block, and guarantees that the memory will be properly deleted if an exception happens before the other shared_ptrs are created.
A very unrolled version of it will look as follows.
{
  std::shared_ptr<chat_session> ptr = std::make_shared<chat_session>(std::move(socket), room_);
  room_.join(ptr);
  ptr->do_read_header();
}


you are looking at an old version of asio documentation 1.39, currently boost asio 1.85 is production-ready, the overload you see of async_accept creates and accepts the socket for you, you only need to pass it the handler of what to do with the socket once the socket is accepted, like starting the communication through the socket.

The secret to what was going on was std::enable_shared_from_this. That needs more emphasis. Good write.
